# conan install fails on name and version field

Tags: linux, conan

relevant files:
`.
├── bin 
├── src
├── conanfile.py
└── gcc-9.3.0-linux-x86-debug.profile`

When trying to run the following command from the bin folder, I get the error that the name and the version field is not found in the profile.
`$ conan install .. --profile ../gcc-9.3.0-linux-x86-debug.profile
ERROR: Error reading '../gcc-9.3.0-linux-x86-debug.profile' profile: Specify the 'name' and the 'version'`

But if I understand it correctly, the version and name should be defined in the conanfile.py file. Where would I define missing name and version number for the install command?

Relevant conan profile

```
[build_requires]
cmake
ninja
gcc/9.3.0
g++/9.3.0
xorriso

qemu


[settings]
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
arch=x86
arch_build=x86
compiler=gcc
compiler.version=9.3.0
cppstd=17
build_type=Debug

[options]

[env]
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-9.3.0
CXX=/usr/bin/g++-9.3.0
CFLAGS=-g
CXXFLAGS=-g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the version too in the `[build_requires]` (same in `conanfile.txt` and `conanfile.py` files). Specifying only the name is not valid syntax. So something like:

```
[build_requires]
cmake/3.16.4
```

If you need it, version ranges are possible, something like `cmake/[>3.15]` for example should work.